# How do I fork the Uniswap V2 interface?

Tags: fork, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am already done forking the smart contracts of the Uniswap, I am looking at forking the interface and then linking it up with the smart contract, is there a guide or way I can do this, I can't seem to find how to do this.